# Telegram Bot File Download Suddenly response 403

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot and it was working without any problem since yesterday( 5/9/2018 )
but now it receives 403 when trying to download a file. I didn't see any change in Bot API documents. Even when I try to download the file manually I get 403. The problem isn't seen in my other bots.

I know the process (first making a getFile request and then generate the direct file path from file_path in the response) but when I try to download the file from generated url (`https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`) it returns 403.

**More Info:**

I send the file by my own user to the bot, so neither the file message is deleted nor the file owner is deactivated or cleared history or somthing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that there were a bug in Telegram Service. Cause the problem disappeared a month later. I contacted telegram and ask them for the reason but I got no answer, by the way, as the problem solved without any change in my code, I think it was a bug on Telegram Service.

Comment: Now i gave you +10 so i am 13 points behind you Bob ( Patric )

Comment: hi saeed. do u have this problem again? It happened to me tonight

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if the file was deleted from a dialog by user himself. In this case Telegram delete files physically from storage and throw 403 error.

I also suspect that Telegram also delete all files from dialog history if user clear history (but I'm not 100% sure in that, but it's quite logically).

If this answer doesn't help you, provide more information:
* What type of chat?
* Who sent that file (user or bot)?

Comment: I added more info in my question

Comment: @saeed can you find that file in the history with bot?